# Installing updates on an expired Windows 10 Insider Program build

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, windows-insider

I have switched to the Windows Insider Program some time ago and my build has expired. I have un-enrolled from this program and now I want to have the regular updates and experiences. Yet, for some reason, my windows update is still attempting to install Windows 11 (which I do not want and should not be getting) and is not able to install any other updates.

How do I get back my Windows 10 updates back without a clean reinstall?

My build version is 21359.1.

Comment: I am pretty sure you will need to install Windows 10 fresh. That is one of the provisos of the Insider Program.

Comment: From this link it seems that switching to stable from dev (what I want) is possible but there is no real info on it . https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/how-do-i-change-dev-channel-to-stable-channel/195b8884-f838-4ea2-bc07-784dd6287ca4

Comment: If your build has expired I do not think you can switch back.

Comment: Your options are extremely limited. [Edit] your question and specify the exact build you are on.  It’s not possible to downgrade to a build lower than the one you have installed. Do not provide this vital information in a comment

Comment: @Ramhound I am definitely not looking to downgrade. I am clearly looking to take in new updates and my build is clearly relatively old (expired).

Comment: Your comment doesn’t provide me the necessary information to answer your question.I am not suggesting you are looking to downgrade your installation, I am informing you, it’s impossible to do so.The reason I am looking for that information is due to fact there is one interim Windows 10 Insider Build that was right before the first Windows 11 build. If you are on that build your only choice will be to upgrade to Windows 11 or perform a clean install.Likewise, if your actually on a Windows 11 Insider Build, your only choice is to go to the stable W11 build. Hence the reason I asked what I asked.

Comment: While you compile that vital information. Provide a screenshot of the Insider Preview panel within Settings

Comment: Updated version number. Thanks for the clarification. The initial comments on downgrading made me think that my wording was suggesting interest in a downgrade.

Comment: My build version is 21359.1.  - That is a Windows 11 build or late Windows 10 build which means you ARE running Windows 11. No way back to Windows 10 at this point without reinstalling Windows 10.

Comment: @John - It’s not actually Windows 11, it’s literally the first build of branch, that became Windows 11 3 months later. It’s still technically Windows 10, this is one of the reasons, Insider Preview builds must be constantly updated otherwise you get into a situation where there is no solution.  I had a VM with a similar problem but itself had other issues (SFC, DISM) all returned errors and refused to run, and because I was on an interim build between two releases, I had no upgrade path (even if it would upgrade and not rollback)

Comment: General FYI, and especially when using Insider Builds, move user data _(e.g. `%UserProfile%\Documents`, `%UserProfile%\Downloads`, etc.)_ to its own partition via each folder's Properties' Location tab, separating it from the OS partition _(~300GB is the max size the OS partition needs to be when user data is stored on a separate partition)_

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get back my Windows 10 updates back without a clean reinstall?
>
> My build version is 21359.1

What you want is impossible. You have a Windows 10 Insider Preview build released back in April 2021, which was approximately 3 months before Windows 11 was announced. Since there are no additional Windows 10 Insider Preview builds on that development branch, and the current stable build is 19044, your only choice to avoid a clean install is to upgrade to Windows 11.

Microsoft’s plan for Windows 10 21H2 changed, the build you have installed was going to be a future Windows 10 feature update, instead it turned into Windows 11 and Microsoft decided to make Windows 10 21H2 the last version (at this present time) for Windows 10 that will be released.

The first Windows 11 22H2 build is 21390.1010 and was released in July 2021 with the final build for it was released in October 2021 and was 22000.282.

Since 22000 is higher than your current build, other than the current Windows 11 22H2 Insider Preview build and what will eventually become Windows 11 23H2 Insider Preview build there are no other builds of Windows 10 or Windows 11 you can upgrade to (other than long expired Windows 11 21H2 Insider Preview builds).

Comment: So you could technically upgrade to 21390.2025 but also has long expired, so you wouldn’t gain anything from doing so and would be in an identical situation just on a more recent expired Insider Preview pre-Windows 11 build.

Comment: Unfortunately my computer is not compatible with Windows 11 so I am stuck here. Thanks for your help. Can I do anytthing with this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/how-do-i-change-dev-channel-to-stable-channel/195b8884-f838-4ea2-bc07-784dd6287ca4?

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft's
[Updating from an expiring Insider Preview build](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/build-expiration):

> To move off the Insider Preview build expiring on your device, you can either get preview builds in the Dev Channel, reinstall Windows using a Windows Insider ISO to move to the Beta channel, or start fresh with a clean installation of Windows 10.

The only viable option here is a fresh installation of Windows 10.
Remember to backup first your data.